# How to get ggplot aes(col=var) effect without changing line color

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I make this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=1990:2001, y=rnorm(5), z=c("a","b","c"))

ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y, col=z)) +
  geom_line()
```

execpt with the lines all in the same color? I don't know whether there is another `aes` argument to use or something else to do.

This doesn't do anything:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y, col=z), col="black") +
  geom_line()
```

And this merges all the lines into one:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y, col=z)) +
  geom_line(col="black")
```

Comment: try `ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y, group=z)) +  geom_line()`

Comment: The real trick here is `ggplot2` looking to global `aes()` first in terms of setting plot conditions (color here). Also `ggplot2` is looking for a aes(group= ?)` even if you don't specify one originally and it will assume that the vector assigned to color `aes(color = b)` is in fact grouping your data somehow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want separate lines for every distinct z you can use the group argument

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y, group=z)) + geom_line()
```

If you want to give all lines a color, but the same you need to specify it outside of the aesthetics like this

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=x, y=y, group=z)) + geom_line(color = "blue")
```